# Unable to read whitespaces when reading from a dat file in java

Tags: java

I am trying to read a dat file and store column names.
The first line in the file is separated by spaces.
The following code is unable to split the column names from the line

```
FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream("file.dat");
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
String line=br.readLine();``
String k[]=line.split(" ");
```

if i print k[0] it prints the entire line and the same does not happen if its a text file. What should i do to read the white space

Comment: Would you provide us the content of your `file.dat`? Your code should work well and store words separated with a whitespace (`" "`) to the array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible that the fields are separated by whitespace other than the simple `" "` space. You can try splitting by any kind of whitespace with:

```
String k[]=line.split("\\s");
```

If this doesn't work either, the data is not separated by whitespace. Try using a hex editor/viewer to see what the separator character is.

Comment: Perhaps `\\s+` would be a better regex since OP says "The first line in the file is separated by spaces.", `\\s` would include empty strings in the resulting split array. Good point though.